# Calling sprites from texture atlas without using starling in action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip, texture-atlas

Is there anyway to use a texture atlas without using starling framework in flash?

Everywhere i looked for related tutorials it's all about starling framework. I suppose there must be a way to embed the texture atlas without using starling.

The starling movie clip is a bit different from actionscript3 movie clip, so that's where i'm having problems.

Comment: Technically, if atlas is not in ATF format, it is possible. But there's no point to it. **Starling** use texture atlases because it is GPU-efficient. Without **Starling** it is simpler and more performance-efficient to just use separate images, rather then glue them into atlases.

Comment: @Sahran, what problem are you trying to solve by using texture atlas?

Comment: I am trying to code a game. Basically there are some pieces over the board and some cards in each player hand. 
Whenever a player uses a card and applies it to a piece i need the related effect to be played.
Right now i'm using different movie clips for each effect. But the library is way too crowded, I was wondering if I could use a texture atlas for the effects sprites. 
I was gonna use starling, but I wasn't sure if I have to  rewrite the mechanics or not cause I found out some of the syntax in starling is different from the classic flash.

Comment: @Sahran If you target mobile devices, you should start learning Starling anyway - otherwise your game will be slow, laggy, and eat far too much battery. Otherwise, just structure your Library (you can have folders there, you know), or maybe go with external SWF libraries for content. As I said above, the atlases are needless technical complication without Starling and will result in reduced performance and memory overuse.

Comment: Yes, I target mobile devices, and actually as u said, whenever i publish for android the game fps drops, however i'm now testing on desktop windows.

So if u think it's essential to use starling, I better do it right away.
So if i get it right, the library is not a big of an issue, and I don't need an atlas for a desktop game, however if I'm targeting a mobile device i should use starling.
Thanks man.

Comment: @Organis, much appreciated. U are the best.

Comment: @Sahran I don't just "think" that, **Starling** allows you to switch rendering from CPU (default Flash behavior) which is powerful on desktop computers but pretty weak on mobile devices to GPU. Then, if you are doing that anyway, there's no reason to create a non-**Starling** version for desktop. Why is that? First, **Starling** works just fine on desktops too. Second, you will find keeping two projects (with a slightly different codebases) rather tiresome very soon.

Comment: Thanks man, I'll go with Starling, I find ur insight actually very important cause i would never know, it's crucial. Thanks, u changed everything.